# Running chat listeners in background

Tags: android, service, background, asmack, listeners

I am making a application using asmack. i want to ask is that asmack have listeners like chat listeners, message listener and when we create a room there are many listeners realted to the chat-rooms. These listeners runs in the background thread, but will all these listerners will run if app is moved to the background, or we need to make a service class for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listeners will be run within the thread that calls them. This is usually Smack's PacketReader thread. Android Apps are not moved in background, but something similar happens to [Android Activities](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). You still want to use a sticky non-foreground Android service to hold the reference to your XMPPConnection.

Comment: so if i call the listener from the activity it will be keep on running until activity is not get stopped or destroyed? but if activity gets pause will it be still running? So there is no need to make a separate service class for this?